# Use server tag in an anchor tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to use a property ID value in the anchor tag as below:

```
<a id="aExample" href="/test/example.aspx?id=<%# Id %>" runat="server">Example</a>
```

But when the page is rendered instead of getting the href as `"/test/example.aspx?id=5"` i am getting `"/test/example.aspx?id=<%# Id %>"` as plain text assigned as href of the anchor.

Id = is a property defined in code behind.

Can anybody help me whats wrong with this?
N.B: I need runat="server"` to be present.

My tag is not inside any Grid view control but within a user control. <%=

Comment: Why not assign it's `href` in the code behind?

Comment: a tag is inside gridvie or datalist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this,

```
<a id="aExample" href='<%# string.Format("/test/example.aspx?id={0}", Id) %>'  runat="server">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

if you want get variable value from your .cs so you can use.
Declare variable in your page.
`.cs` page

```
 public int Id = 0;
```

`aspx` page

```
<a id="aExample" href="/test/example.aspx?id=<%= Id %>" runat="server">Example</a>
```

and your a tag is inside in gridview control so you can use like...

```
<a id="aExample" href="/test/example.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Id")%>" runat="server">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a id="aExample" href='<%= CompleteURL %>' runat="server">Example</a>
```

If you can build and bind the complete URL in your property (code behind). I think this can be optimal solution. This way you can also change your URL dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="aExample" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("/test/example.aspx?id={0}", Eval("Id")) %>'>Example</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code behind  (if its not inside Gridview or some other control like that)

```
aExample.Href = "/test/example.aspx?id="+ YourEntity.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `href` of anchor tag in `CodeBehind`.

**CodeBehind:**

```
int Id = 4;
aExample.HRef = "/test/example.aspx?id=" + Id;
```

Thanks